# Unable to deal with "traits cannot have type parameters with context bound"

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I a have the models:

```
case class MyModel1(id: UUID, a: Int, b: String...)
case class MyModel2(id: Long, c: Int, d: String...)
```

And I want some of them to be able to convert themselves to JSON.

```
trait Jsonable[T] {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val writer: Writes[T] = Json.writes[T]
}

trait JsonableId[TId, T] extends Jsonable[T] {

  implicit val pkIdWriter = Writes[Pk[TId]] { pkId => JsString(pkId.get.toString) }
  implicit val idWriter = Writes[TId] { id => JsString(id.toString) }
}
```

And when I say:

```
object MyModel1 extends JsonableId[Long, MyModel1] {
  def single(a: Long) = //.....
}
```

It throws an error `No unapply function found`. Well, I tried to do this:

```
trait Jsonable[T: {def unapply(a: T): Option[T]}] {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val writer: Writes[T] = Json.writes[T]
}
```

But the error was `traits cannot have type parameters with context bound`.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work just because macro-implemented method `Json.writes` has not enough information about `T`.

`No unapply function found` is not the only error message you'll get, it's just the first one.

If you want to use duck typing you should use `T <: {def unapply(a: T): Option[T]}`. With `T: {def unapply(a: T): Option[T]}` you are trying to add an implicit parameter of type `{def unapply(a: T): Option[T]}[T]` and this makes no sense.

Any way: it will not help you: `writesImpl` macro can't find an `unapply` method in companion object, not in `T` itself. I guess it should fail even earlier with error like `No companion object found` or even `Call this method with case class name as type parameter`.

So the answer: don't try to do this. Just add `implicit val writer: Writes[T] = Json.writes[MyModel1]` manually.

The only way to implement "something like this" is to add such implicit parameter into companion object using macro-implemented annotation like this:

```
@withWrites case class MyModel1(id: UUID, a: Int, b: String...)
@withWrites case class MyModel2(id: Long, c: Int, d: String...)
```

Comment: I forgot unapply method should be in a companion object.